# Reactive spring boot for correlation between request and response in async application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rx-java, reactive

I am a newbie in reactive programming. I did some research but could not find any satisfactory answer. My requirement is to correlate request and response using reactive programming (using spring boot) in a asynchronous set up.

In detail - My organization application architecture has front end, middleware and legacy backend. Front end makes a call to middleware which talks to legacy backend over MQ. At the moment call to backend is synchronous over MQ. We are trying to uplift the experience by making the backend call asynchronous. So in this setup front end will make a call over http/rest to middleware which puts the message over MQ to be consumed by legacy systems. Once legacy system is done with processing, it will put the message back on to another queue which will in turn be picked up by middleware again and send back to front end systems. In this set up my job is to correlate the request/response in the middle layer. We have one option to use DB but I want to see whether it is possible to use reactive java for the same.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.